# websocket асинхронные запросы клиентов к одной async функции сервера

Tags: node.js, websocket, async-await, асинхронность

пишу систему сбора данных, использую WebSoket на Node.JS.

Клиенты обращаются к серверу, сервер в свою очередь, запрашивает с помощью асинхронной функции данные от "железки" (т.е. надо подождать пока ответит "железка").

Данные запрашиваются клиентом с максимально возможной частотой (около 300 раз в сек), как только сервер ответил, сразу отправляется новый запрос.

Пока клиент один - всё отлично. Когда добавляется второй клиент, то, так как обращаются к одной и той же асинхронной функции, начинают друг другу мешать, порой на несколько секунд подвешивая связь.

Как правильно спроектировать приложение сервера в такой ситуации? Напрашивается создание очереди доступа к асинхронной функции с ожиданием ответа на запрос к данной функции от конкретного сокета. Наверняка кто-то сталкивался с подобным поведением (например асинхронная функция - запрос с длительным обращением к БД) и как-то побеждал проблему.

Я менял эту функцию на синхронную (выдаёт некий похожий на реальный JSON) - тогда все сервер работает без сбоев.

Comment: "начинают друг другу мешать" - что это значит?

Comment: сокеты вызывают одну и туже async функцию, передавая ей различные (ведь у каждого сокета свой запрос) параметры. Функция возвращает Promice... но это же не выстраивает автоматически очередь вызовов данной функции с разными параметрами, результат работы которой должен вернуться вызвавшему её сокету?

Comment: Я думаю дело не в асинхроности, а в параллельности обработки запросов от разных клиентов.

Comment: У меня такие же предположения... какие есть рецепты?

Comment: Я ничего не понял в этом вопросе. Вы горите что у вас лонгполлинг с частотой 300 раз в секунду, так причём тут тогда вебсокеты? Вебсокеты - это полная противоположность лонгполлингу, их задача в том, чтобы ничего не опрашивать! И если вы говорите, что вам **надо** подождать пока ответит железка, значит вам **надо** использовать синхронную функцию! По-моему вы пытаетесь забивать гвозди микроскопом.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, сервер должен опрашивать "железку" и хранить наиболее актуальные данные у себя, в какой-то переменной. Когда приходит запрос, то в ответе ему возвращается текущее значение этой переменной.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/451725)

Comment: Почему не является ответом? Автор сформулировал свой вопрос так: Как правильно спроектировать приложение сервера в такой ситуации? Я предложил своё видение архитектуры предложения.